# Completely delete + purge/expunge IMAP folders using Python imaplib

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm using this script to bulk delete empty IMAP folders:  https://gitlab.com/puzzlement/delete-empty-imap-dirs

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getpass, imaplib, sys, argparse

import parseNested

IGNORE = set(["INBOX", "Postponed", "Sent", "Sent Items", "Trash", "Drafts", "MQEmail.INBOX", "MQEmail.Outbox", "MQEmail.Postponed"])

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='This script deletes empty remote IMAP folders.')
    parser.add_argument('--port', '-p', metavar='PORT', type = int,
            help = 'Port number to connect to (143 or 993/SSL used by default)')
    parser.add_argument("-quiet", "--q",
                      action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                      help="don't print status messages to standard error")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--ssl",
                      action="store_true", dest="ssl", default=False,
                      help="Use SSL encryption")
    parser.add_argument('hostname', help="Domain name/host name of IMAP "
            "server to delete folders on")
    parser.add_argument('username', help="Username/login "
            "on IMAP server")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.ssl:
        IMAPClass = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL
    else:
        IMAPClass = imaplib.IMAP4
    if args.port:
        M = IMAPClass(args.hostname, args.port)
    else:
        M = IMAPClass(args.hostname)
    M.login(args.username, getpass.getpass('IMAP password for user %s at server %s: ' % (args.username, args.hostname)))
    listresponse = M.list()
    mailboxes = []
    for chunk in listresponse[1]:
        nested = parseNested.parseNestedParens(chunk)
        if '\\HasNoChildren' in nested[0] and '\\NoSelect' in nested[0]:
            if args.verbose:
                sys.stderr.write("%s has no children and is not selectable, deleting\n" % nested[2])
            M.delete(nested[2])
        
        elif not '\\HasChildren' in nested[0]:
            mboxname = nested[2]
            ignoretest = set([])
            ignoretest.add(mboxname)
            ignoretest.add("INBOX." + mboxname)
            ignoretest.add(mboxname.lstrip("INBOX."))
            if not ignoretest.intersection(IGNORE):
                mailboxes.append(mboxname)
    for mailbox in mailboxes:
        reply, data = M.select(mailbox)
        if reply != 'OK':
            print >> sys.stderr, "Cannot select mailbox '%s', reply was '%s', skipping" % (mailbox, str(data[0]))
            continue
        else:
            nomessages = int(data[0])
            M.close()
            if nomessages == 0:
                if args.verbose:
                    sys.stderr.write("%s is empty of messages, deleting\n" % mailbox)
                M.delete(mailbox)
    M.logout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's using [this line of code](https://gitlab.com/puzzlement/delete-empty-imap-dirs/-/blob/master/deleteEmptyIMAPFolders.py#L63) to delete the folders:

```
M.delete(mailbox)
```

However this doesn't seem to completely delete the folders:

- In Outlook, the folders remain there like nothing happened
- In Thunderbird, the folder names change from having black text to gray
- In the webmail at the host (Network Solutions), the folders are gone
- If I re-run this Python script again, it doesn't see the folders it deleted on the previous run

I know that IMAP has 2 steps for deleting actual ***email messages*** (delete, then purge/expunge)... so I'm guessing this is something similar, but I can't find much info on how this works with ***folders*** on IMAP anywhere at all.

How can I:

1. Have this Python script see the "partially deleted" folders again, on subsequent runs
2. Have it fully delete all traces of the folders, i.e. do any kind of purge/expunge needed

Comment: It is also possible that the server (quietly?) refuses to delete folders it requires (I would guess Microsoft), and/or that the client will recreate folders it regards as "standard" if you try to move messages into them, rather than fail until you manually recreate them.

Comment: True story: On an Exchange server (at work, not my choice; don't ask) I set my preferences to Greenland for a brief experiment (anound time zones IIRC) and now I have several folders with names in Danish which absolutely cannot be deleted.

Comment: @tripleee - I see the same behavior regardless of the folder name, including the non-standard ones.  

Not sure which daemon it is, the IMAP server host is: mail0.hostingplatform.com

Comment: DELETE is the only command to delete a folder, though it may be refused.  Make sure to check your result codes!

Comment: @Max are you 100% sure about this?  If the delete command was failing, then I'd still be seeing the "not-actually-deleted folders" when I re-run the Python script.  But they're gone from the 1st run.  Also gone from Claws email client, yet still exist for Outlook + Thunderbird (grayed) - even when I create entirely new account profiles and sync from scratch.

Comment: Yes I am. The reference for IMAP is RFC 3501 and I have written/contributed to multiple email clients.

Comment: Thunderbird is possibly showing you a cached folder.

Comment: @Max Ok thanks.  Yeah I wondered about caching/local-data issues in both Outlook + Thunderbird.  But when I create entirely new profiles and set the account up from scratch, and sync for the very first time from nothing... all these folders are still there.  Yet they're not listed in the Python script, nor Claws email client or webmail at Network Solutions.  In the Python script above, anything you think I can add that might make it list folders that it isn't currently?  Maybe something related to the "NoChild" flags or something like that?

Comment: If you have child folders, the parent has to "exist" to hold the children, even if it's not a real folder.  There's a concept of a \NoSelect folder that exists, but can't hold email.

Comment: @Max Ok thanks.  In this case the folders are all at the very top-level.  No sub-folders to deal with.  Was just wondering if there might be any other flags that could affect visibility depending on client.

Comment: Some clients will use LIST (all folders), and some will use LSUB (subscribed folders, this list can be changed using SUBSCRIBE and UNSUBSCRIBE commands).      Perhaps your server has a bug where it's showing nonexistent subscribed folders?  You can run lsub() with imaplib and seeing if you're getting a significantly different list, or see if it's returning stale data.

Comment: Note, I see you're trying to delete \NoSelect folders.  Those usually already _are_ "deleted" and are existing for some other reason (having child folders, or being namespace roots are the only reasons I can think of, but maybe there are others.)

Comment: Thanks so much @Max !  You've basically solved my issue.  Yes it was subscriptions to folders that don't exist.  While looking into it further I noticed this comment https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/2474#issuecomment-199004245 re the IMAP spec not requiring that servers remove subscriptions to non-existent folders.  You mentioned it might be a server bug, so in this case re that part of the RFC, should it technically be considered a bug to fix? Or just an implementation design choice, compliant with RFC?  Just wondering if I should tell the host to fix anything or not.

Comment: According to the spec it is not a bug, apparently, so I would just add .unsubscribe to your script. 
I think it’s weird for LSUB to return folders that don’t currently exist. The RFC does indicate the subscribe must be maintained, but is ambiguous as to whether LSUB should return them. Personally I think the behaviour here is weirder than the situation it’s trying to prevent.

Comment: I will write an answer since it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IMAP4Rev1, there are a couple reasons why a folder may continue to exist in some form after you DELETE it:

- It has child folders (it will then appear as a \NoSelect folder).
- It is a required system folder
- Or it is still subscribed

In the latter case, the folder does not exist, but the server may continue to return it as result to the `LSUB` command, which some clients use to present their heirarchy.

You could add `M.unsubscribe()` to your folder deletion code to remove it from the subscription list as well. You may also need to use `M.lsub()` to find these folders.