# Does the IMAP protocol have a 2 step deletion process for folders in the same way it does for email messages? (2nd step being purge/expunge)

Tags: email, protocols, imap, email-client, rfc

I'm trying to troubleshoot some very strange issue with different email clients and IMAP scripts giving me different folders.  Folders that have been "deleted" from the account are still visible in Outlook + Thunderbird, but gone from other clients/scripts.  This includes when I set up an entirely new profile in Outlook/Thunderbird.

In order to progress at all, I need to get an answer to the fundamental question:

IMAP has 2 steps to delete ***email messages*** (not folders):

1. Delete the message
2. Purge/expunge it

**I want to know:** does the IMAP protocol (or certain implementations) also have anything similar for IMAP ***folders***?

I've scoured the web, but can't find anything about this for ***folders***.  But I can't understand the inconsistencies I'm seeing with my scripting (in multiple languages) and various email clients.

Note that the folders in question here are ***not*** any of the special folders that exist for all users by default (or that MUA clients auto-create).  These are just user-created folders with various non-special names.

Comment: No. The standard for this is RFC 3501.  There is no second step.

Comment: Well, uhm. IMAP has parent folders and child folders. If you delete a parent folder, it may well becomes unselectable and all the mail in it goes away, but it doesn't quite go away, because the children need it. It depends on the server. If you want to delete many folders, delete the children first, because parents don't keep children half-alive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely delete + purge/expunge IMAP folders using Python imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74499286/completely-delete-purge-expunge-imap-folders-using-python-imaplib)

Comment: Voting to close as dupe as this is now answered adequately in your other question.  It turns out the server was keeping deleted folders in the subscribed lists, and some clients use LSUB.

Comment: @Max They're same topic, but different question, so people will arrive to them from different google queries.  I don't see how anyone benefits from closing questions like this that could potentially help people in the future.  Especially when the questions are left online and indexed on search engines anyway, but just blocked from answering.  It's ridiculous, and wastes everyone's time, and makes these sites infuriating to so many of us.  Happy to mark you as the answer here too if you write one.  Thanks for all your help.